# How to display characters using number 1 to 26 with one complexity

Tags: c#, c++

i want to display characters a to z by using 1 to 26 numbers and its complexity must be one.
any solution plz tell me. thanks
I am trying it through for loop but then its complexity increase from 1.

Comment: What's wrong with just using a table, indexed by the number?

Comment: what do you mean can you please elaborate. what about its complexity?

Comment: @user3045220: this is a slightly awkward question in C++. It's much easier if you're permitted to assume that the system uses ASCII as its character encoding, but that is not required by the C++ standard.

Comment: can you provide some code example please? i have to messed with it.

Comment: Do you mean `char c = (char)((int)'a' + number - 1);` ? or... what *do* you mean - this is very unclear... and example of what you are trying to represent would help

Answer (score 1):

Just use an array:

```
char const translate[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
for ( int i = 1; i <= 26; ++ i ) {
    std::cout << translate[i - 1];
}
```

The problem is simply one of code translation, and anytime there
is a one to one relationship in the codes, a translation table
is the simplest.

For the rest, it's not clear what you mean by the complexity;
the complexity for converting a single number into a single
character here is O(1), but I'm not sure what it is measured
against.  If you want it against the number of characters being
output, it's impossible to achieve O(1), since the output itself
is O(n).

Answer (score 0):

If you are refering to the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity it can only be done in a program with no conditional (if, for ...) because each branch increments the complexity by 1
In my opinon the only solution is:

```
i=0;
putchar('A'+(i++));
putchar('A'+(i++));
putchar('A'+(i++));
...
putchar('A'+(i++));
```

Too simple makes things complicated ;-)

Comment: Of course, in terms of *output*, the entire thing (and this is a fault of the question, not the answer) can be replaced by any "print" method passed the literal `"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"` - which is, by any measure, much less "complexity"

Comment: I'm pretty certain that "complexity must one one" is intended to mean that the running time to display each character is required to be `O(1)`.

Comment: @MarcGravell But still O(n) with regards to the length of the string.

Comment: @SteveJessop I can't think of any other applicable sense, either, but...  Do you know of any algorithm for one to one code translation that isn't O(1)?

Comment: @JamesKanze: assuming this is a homework-style question, I would guess that the restriction is either intended to rule out stupidly inefficient handling of the data once it's looked up, or else is intended to rule out using a `std::map` or linear search for the lookup itself. Either of those lookups of course would still be O(1), since there are a constant number (26) of elements being searched, but you know what people are like with imprecise statements of complexity :-)

Comment: @JamesKanze that's no different to the line-by-line version being O(N) with regards the number of characters hard-coded in the question

Comment: This answer assumes that capital letters are represented by contiguous increasing values. That is **not** required by the C or C++ language definitions; in fact, there are character representations for which it does not hold.

Answer (score 0):

This code print char from ascii code, from 'A' to 'Z'.

```
for(int i=0; i != 27; ++i) {
   cout << (char)(i + 65) << " ";
}
```

Comment: Of course, not all machines use ASCII (and the language doesn't require it).